# Deployment error with Xamarin android application in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to make a blank `Android` application with `Xamarin` platform in `Visual Studio 2015`. For that I have installed `VS2015` with `Xamarin` and tried to make an application for `Android`. However when I try to run it, it gives an error at deployment without showing any error message even if the build succeeded. I am using Emulator(AVD) by 512 RAM.

I have tried to clean solution, rebuild, and run as administrator but could not trace any error. I have also searched on SO for the hints but could not find any.

[image: Here is error message]

Comment: can you please share screenshot which showing deployment error?

Comment: It is showing simple pop up window by the message _there was deployment error. Do you want to continue?_

Comment: after continue does it display something??

Comment: no, It is not showing anything :(

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer without seeing actual screen. If you are deploying application in android device, check whether device is developer unlock or not. If you are using simulator check its setting, that's only i can suggest.

Comment: any luck?? if you find the solution, please update

Comment: Can you show build log output? (select 'Build' in 'Show output from' dropdown in output view)

Comment: Actually it is showing_Please select a valid device to run this application_. While in AVD it is howing an error for _an repairable AVD that failed to load_.

Comment: This shows that there is a problem with your emulator. Please review this article https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/configure_emulator/

Comment: yea, It is already suggested in below comments, my emulator has these settings exactly but unable to deploy still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: Do you want it to deploy on a real device or on Emulator?
Second: Have you openend the [Android Device Logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dti8A.png) (Logcat)?

Third: I assume you want to deploy it on a real device and no errors in the logs.

Visual Studio 2015 has a very "interesting" behaviour on deploying to my nexus test device.

The deploy only works if I "Clean" the solution first and Run it afterwards. If I make a clean and / or a rebuild and then run it, the deploy fails :(.

So please try to clean und run it afterwards and see if the deploy is successful.
Here is my [AVD Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7UwS.png)

Comment: Did you have a look at the Android Device Logging? Did you deploy on device or Emulator?

Comment: What you can else try is look at the Debug Window. There is a Dropdown list. Select in "Show output from" not Debug. Instead select Xamarin and build again.

Comment: When i select _Xamarin Diagnostics_ in output widow, Its says **avd watcher error: load process of avd devices failed, please check the following error: The system cannot find the path specified.**

Comment: I have added screenshot of an error which is continuous :(

Comment: Please have a look at my AVD setting (attached screenshot). What I else did is, set the heap size of the Java to 1G. You find this in your Android Project under Proprties. There go to "Android Options" and open the Tab Advanced. There you fill in 1G into "Java Max Heap Size". I know it is hard and sometimes frustrating to get something to run with Xamarin. I spent a lot of time to get things to work :( From my point of view it looks like your emulators are not correct set up.

Comment: Maybe this site has also some tips for you! https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/configure_emulator/

Comment: Thanks, Now working properly, actually I download appropriate sdk from android sdk manager.

Comment: Perfect, glad it works now, however you solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your emulator. I've had this issue before with emulators, and a restart worked everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Right-click on your android project and click properties then go to the android options menu then uncheck the 'Use fast deployment'

Option 2:
uninstall the old version of the app from your device

Answer (score -1):

You need to open ADB and try to connect with your emulator using ADB Connect (Your emulator IP Address)